# problem with lag function in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, subquery, window-functions

there is following code to create table in sqlite3

```
import sqlite3 as sq
con = sq.connect('test2.db')
q = """ 
    create table if not exists test (ip TEXT, time INTEGER, value INTEGER);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.1", 1607190826, 3010);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.1", 1607190827, 3012);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.1", 1607190828, 3019);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.2", 1607190829, 510);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.2", 1607190829, 515);
    insert into test (ip, time, value) values("192.168.1.2", 1607190829, 530);
    """
con.executescript(q)
con.commit()
```

I use lag function in sqlite like this

```
qw = """SELECT ip, lag(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ip) val2 from test"""

f = con.execute(qw)
for i in f:
  print(i)
```

but I got the following error code.

```
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

**UPDATE**

It work with python 3.7.

I still have problem with python 3.6

Comment: Execute `select sqlite_version();` to check your version of SQLite. Window functions were introduced in version 3.25.0.

Comment: the version is '3.22.0'.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-3.25 versions of SQLite, where window functions are not supported, you can emulate `lag()` with a correlated subquery.

From your sample data, I suspect that you want the previous `value` for the same `ip`, as ordered by `time` - which is not what your code does. The window function version for that would be:

```
select ip, lag(value, 1, 0) over(partition by ip order by time) as val2
from test
```

And the equivalent subquery solution goes like:

```
select ip, 
    coalesce(
        (
            select value 
            from test t1 
            where t1.ip = t.ip and t1.time < t.time
            order by t1.time desc limit 1
        ), 
        0
    ) as val2 
from test t
```

Comment: it works but I use pandas dataframe and diff method.